# ¿El primer uso de artículo indefinido en esta frase es correcto?

Tags: artículos

¿Les parece gramaticalmente correcta esta oración?

> Un ordenador es una herramienta muy útil

En particular, el uso del primer artículo indefinido. Ahora bien, si les parece correcta gramaticalmente, ¿les parece natural fuera de contexto? Si no, ¿en qué situación la usarían, por ejemplo? ¿Le agregarían algo para hacerla más aceptable o natural?

Comment: Suena bien. De todas formas, iría bien que usaras [edit] para añadir más información relevante: ¿en qué contexto? ¿dónde (puede variar por países)? ¿qué búsqueda has hecho al respecto?

Comment: Esta pregunta podría se interesante y válida si fuese "Por qué es necesario" o "Podría no usar el artículo...". Tal como está, es offtopic. A pesar de que una pregunta puede tener varias respuesta, se espera que las respuestas estén razonadas (dar una explicación de **por qué** la frase es correcta o no lo es). Aquellas que preguntan por opinión personal, hacen varias preguntas en el mismo post, etc. son consideradas demasiado abiertas como para ser respondidas satisfactoriamente en el formato de ese sitio.

Comment: Gracias, fedorqui: Aquí añadí más información. Los juicios gramaticales simples son más que suficientes. Diego: yo creo que la pregunta es completamente válida. Al decir: "¿Porqué es necesario...? o ¿Podría no usar el artículo...?" estoy asumiendo que para ti el uso es necesario. Es entonces una pregunta guiada y esa no era mi intención. A lo que apelo es a tu instinto de nativo; que des la respuesta que puedes dar desde tu punto de vista. Tu opinión personal. Espero que la pregunta esté más clara ahora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La oración es gramaticalmente perfecta, puedes usarla en cualquier contexto que lo desees.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10037)

Comment: - ¿Les parece gramatical?
- La oración es gramaticalmente perfecta

- ¿La usarían? Si la usaran, ¿en qué contexto la usarían?
- Puedes usarla en cualquier contexto que lo desees

How is that not an answer for the question?

Comment: Mejor usa [edit] para añadir estas informaciones en tu respuesta. ¡Gracias y bienvenido a [spanish.se]!

Comment: @cventu, yo también estoy e acuerdo en que "is not an answer". El problema no es tanto tu respuesta como la pregunta. La pregunta original es si "parece gramatical" (No entiendo. Tal vez el OP quiere decir "gramaticalmente correcta"?) No queda claro. Además pregunta si el uso del artículo indefinido en la frase es "raro" (de nuevo "??"). Y luego pregunta "En qué contexto usarías en artículo indefinido?" Esta pregunta en general no es clara, es demasiado abierta y las posibles respuestas (aparte de que no se puede responder bien si no se sabe bien qué pregunta) demasiado subjetivas.

Comment: @cventu, gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: @fedorqui, ¡gracias por la bienvenida!

Comment: @Diego, no conocía el nivel de sofisticación lingüístico-teórico de los participantes en este sitio. Como no quería excluir a nadie (porque pregunto por juicios gramaticales, no conocimiento teórico), usé un vocabulario menos técnico...(bueno, excepto por "gramatical": significa "gramaticalmente correcto"-sintaxis). Con "raro", me refiero a "inaceptable" (semántica). Y con "en qué contexto", me refiero a eso mismo, ¿en qué situación usarías esa oración? (pragmática). Gracias por tus comentarios.

Comment: @Daltoniana el nivel de "sofisticación" de los participantes es de hecho nivel aficionado/estudiante. La mayor parte simplemente "juega con ventaja" al ser hablantes nativos. Es la plataforma la que se presta mejor o peor a cierto tipo de preguntas ( :-( ). Si algo es gramaticalmente correcto es objetivo y es fácil de explicar el porqué a alguien que esté aprendiendo. Si algo "_parece_" raro es subjetivo y a la hora de ayudar a alguien a mejorar su nivel de español sólo puedes decir "es mi opinión" en lugar razonar "estas son las normas que suelen seguir los hablantes del lenguaje"

Answer (score 0):

In many situations, I would have said:

```
El ordenador es una herramienta muy útil
```

Spanish often uses the definite article to describe an object in the abstract.  I can't think of exactly when I would use the definite atricle and when I would use the indefinite article.  In normal conversation, I wouldn't even slow down to think about it.  Neither would a native speaker.